# SonarQube - check Groovy indentation

Tags: groovy, sonarqube

Is there an indentation check for Groovy in SonarQube?  I found the `squid:IndentationCheck` for Java, but nothing similar for Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

The groovy SonarQube plugin is relying on CodeNarc rule engine. There does not seem that such a rule exists in CodeNarc at time of writing this message.